# Meaning of "to chat" on Skype

Tags: word-choice

To chat means both:

- to talk in a friendly and informal manner
- to exchange text messages online in real time

How do I remove this ambiguity in a medium such as Skype where both make sense?

If I type "Can we chat when you have a moment" does that imply text messaging or a voice call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "chat" is just a chat.  It doesn't specify the medium.  If you have been "chatting" regularly then the other person will know what you typically do, but otherwise you have to make it explicit.  Here are some examples:

> Let me **text/send** you the details on Skype
>
> Let me **call** you on Skype to go over the details.

Note that nowadays, in addition, you have the choice of a voice-only call and a video call.  The other person may not know which you mean if you don't make it clear:

> Let's do a quick **video call** on Skype to go over the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish them by saying

> Can we do some **text** messaging when you have a moment?

and

> Can we do some **voice** messaging when you have a moment?